# vim: call function on save

Tags: haskell, vim, ghc-mod

I am using ghc-mod in vim and would like GhcModCheck (:GhcModCheck) to be called every time I save a file (:w). Could you please tell me how I can achieve that? I guess there's a more general question: how can I invoke a function on save?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can hook into the `BufWritePost` event. Globally (i.e. for every file):

```
:autocmd BufWritePost * GhcModCheck
```

To do this only for Haskell files, you could modify the file pattern:

```
:autocmd BufWritePost *.hs GhcModCheck
```

But it's better to leverage Vim's built-in *filetype detection* and instead put this into `~/.vim/ftplugin/haskell_OnSave.vim`:

```
:autocmd! BufWritePost <buffer> GhcModCheck
```

Answer (score 4):

There are [Customization tips](https://github.com/eagletmt/ghcmod-vim/wiki/Customize#customization-tips) for ghcmod-vim

One of them is

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.hs GhcModCheckAndLintAsync
```

Which is also the answer for the generic question about executing a specific command on save.